# How to return a char* without the free() or delete?

Tags: c++

I am trying to return char*, but i don't want the function user to delete of free() the memory.

I have the following:

```
namespace name_space 
{
    char* function(unsigned int i);
}

char* name_space::function(unsigned int i)
{
    char buffer[MESSAGE];
    strerror_s(buffer,errno);

    switch(i_exception)
    {
        case MESSAGE_RETURN:            return "No free or delete needed";
        case ERRNO_ERROR:               return buffer;
        default:                        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

When i return the "MESSAGE_RETURN" string no free() or delete is needed. But how can i return buffer without using new or malloc?

Comment: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for all strings?

Comment: returning a pointer to something on the stack? I *smell* access violation

Comment: It's impossible to avoid freeing the memory by the user. You can avoid *explicitley* freeing the memory by returning a C++ object that frees the memory in the destructor. When the object gets out of scope it will be deleted and the memory will be free. This object has a name: `std::string`.

Comment: You may declare buffer as static, but this may cause other problems later if you retain this result in different contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

**Premise:**

Your function `name_space::function` should not `return buffer`.

`buffer` is a *local* (auto) variable, when the function returns it will destroyed. If the caller function tries to access to that memory you will probably receive a *seg-fault* or anyway an UB.

---

**Answer:**

If you need to return a string, what about a simply `std::string`? The dynamic memory will be automatically handled by the class.

For example:

```
#include <string>

std::string name_space::function(unsigned int i) {
    char buffer[MESSAGE];
    strerror_s(buffer, MESSAGE, errno);

    switch (i_exception) {
        case MESSAGE_RETURN:            return "No free or delete needed";
        case ERRNO_ERROR:               return std::string(buffer);
        default:                        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i return this and use `cout << name_space::function(ERRNO_ERROR).c_str() <<endl;` no memory leak?

Comment: @vincentpoortvliet No. When the function will be resolved, after `std::cout` the temporary string will be destroyed and the memory will be free by destructor

Comment: It is not necessary to use `c_str()` to output the string.  C++ streams accept `std::string` as output, so `cout << name_space::function(ERRNO_ERROR) << endl` will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked the question, you are probably aware that there is something wrong with your function, but just to be clear to all readers: The local buffer will be destroyed at the end of the function, so accessing it outside of the function has undefined behaviour. Secondly, your function is declared to return `char*`, while string literals are constant. That makes your program ill-formed since C++11.

A trivial change that would work is to use `strerror` instead, or make the local buffer static. That obviously has the drawback that successive calls to the function will replace the content of previous calls.

A better approach is to delegate the memory handling to a RAII container. A RAII container will allocate the required memory, pass the memory along when moved, and free the memory when destroyed. The conventional RAII container for strings in C++ is the `std::string` from the standard library. Simply return a `std::string`. This change also makes `strerror` a simpler choice:

```
std::string name_space::function(unsigned int i)
{
    switch(i_exception)
    {
        case MESSAGE_RETURN:            return "No free or delete needed";
        case ERRNO_ERROR:               return strerror(errno);
        default:                        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

This approach is also convenient since it avoids potential overflow if your `MESSAGE` is too small. `strerror_s` shouldn't really be used without `strerrorlen_s`.

---

PS. C++ standard library does not inherit the `strerror_s` function from the C standard library, so you cannot rely on it being available in a C++ program. Even in C, that function is part of an optional annex, so it might not be available in a C11 conformant standard library either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strerror()` for this, not `strerror_s()`. The string returned by `strerror()` points to static data and doesn't need to be deleted. Also, do not return string literals, since `function()` returns `char*`, not `const char*`. Either change the return type to `const char*`, or declare static `char[]` variables that hold your error messages.

First option:

```
const char* name_space::function(unsigned int i)
{
    switch(i_exception)
    {
        case MESSAGE_RETURN: return "No free or delete needed";
        case ERRNO_ERROR:    return strerror(errno);
        default:             return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

Second option:

```
char* name_space::function(unsigned int i)
{
    static char msg_no_free[] = "No free or delete needed";
    static char msg_unknown[] = "UNKNOWN";
    switch(i_exception)
    {
        case MESSAGE_RETURN: return msg_no_free;
        case ERRNO_ERROR:    return strerror(errno);
        default:             return msg_unknown;
    }
}
```

However, if you do have the option to use `std::string`, then you should use that instead:

```
std::string name_space::function(unsigned int i)
{
    switch(i_exception)
    {
        case MESSAGE_RETURN: return "No free or delete needed";
        case ERRNO_ERROR:    return strerror(errno);
        default:             return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

In any event, never return a pointer to a non-static local variable, like you currently do. This results in the caller getting a pointer to data that doesn't exist anymore after the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit memory allocation inside your function, you should take buffer from a client:

```
 char* function(char buffer[], size_t capacity, unsigned int i) {

     ...
     return buffer;
 }
```

In that case user can make decision how to allocate buffer:

```
char buffer[1024] = {};
function(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1);
```

or

```
std::vector<char> v(1024);
function(&v[0], v.size(), 1);
```

Comment: In which case it is pointless to return it: it would make more sense to return a count, or an error code.

Comment: agreed, but it is just for example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the playing field but don't want the overhead of `std::string`, simply create your own string_view-style class with an appropriate interface:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace name_space 
{
    // control the playing field - make a proxy class
    struct string_view
    {
        constexpr string_view(const char* p)
        : p_(p)
        {}

        std::string to_string() const { return std::string(p_); }
        std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const {
            return os << p_;
        }
    private:
        const char* p_;
    };

    // give the proxy any required interface
    auto to_string(const string_view& sv) { return sv.to_string(); }
    auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const string_view& sv) -> std::ostream&
    {
        return sv.write(os);
    }


    string_view function(unsigned int i);
}

name_space::string_view name_space::function(unsigned int i)
{
    extern void strerror_s(char*, int);
    constexpr auto MESSAGE = 1024;    
    static char buffer[MESSAGE];
    strerror_s(buffer,errno);

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:            return "No free or delete needed";
        case 2:               return buffer;
        default:                        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `name_space::function` constructs the string view using the local buffer. the string view appears to simply copy the pointer to a member. How is that local buffer still usable after `name_space::function` has returned?

Comment: TBH I don't see how your `string_view` is any different from returning a simple `const char*`. Also it is holding a pointer to a local array (`buffer`) that will get invalidated when the function returns.

Comment: @Galik the question asked how to prevent the deletion of the pointer, not whether the entire enterprise was a good idea.